# How to get web page with proxy in php curl?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, squid

I have installed squid proxy soft on my debian7 ,and start the service.
Everyone can make use of the squid service ,no restriction.
The user and pass were added.

```
/usr/bin/htpasswd -c /etc/squid/passwd testuser
New password: pass
```

The vps can be connected with the `pass` too.

```
ssh  root@vps_ip
```

Now i want to get the web page `http://www.google.com`  with vps_ip as my proxy.

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.google.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'vps_ip:8080');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD,'testuser:pass');
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    echo  $output;
    curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Why there is no output in my firefox when to execute the code ?

Comment: What proxy server is installed on that VPS? Cmdline test connection debugging? Where is the CURLOPT_VERBOSE option?

Comment: Ssh tunnel installed on my vps.Could you tell me to install some sort of proxy server on my remote vps to make the php script run on my local machine?

Comment: Writing tutorials on installing things is off-topic. However, there is Google, which you could have used beforehand.

Comment: I would be very appreciated that if you can give me a little clue, a initial search point to make goolge or baidu run.

Comment: "Install a proxy server on Debian" or something?

Comment: squid installed on my debian 7 ,but the php code still can't get any output.